# C#: Swagger .net Core Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using .net core 3 and using swashbuckle swagger for my api.

When I have the below code:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
   c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;               

});
```

The above code works fine when deployed on my server but locally on my dev machine it errors out:

```
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44352/swagger/index.html
```

I have tried to update the nuget package as well but that dint help out.
Any pointers please

Comment: Try this: https://localhost:44352/swagger/ui/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `https://localhost:44352/`.Refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

> To serve the Swagger UI at the app's root (http://localhost:/),
> set the RoutePrefix property to an empty string:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

It means when you use `c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;`,the RoutePrefix will be empty,and you only need to use address `http://localhost:<port>/` to sever Swagger UI.